# Boinc keeps getting an error/notice saying "virtual box is not installed" on Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, boinc

Trying to crunch some work units from Atlas/LHC@Home, and I keep getting the "virtual box is not installed" error. In Ubuntu 18.04, I installed the following packages that were in the Ubuntu repo:

- boinc (Metapackage 7.9.3)
- boinc-client (Core Client 7.9.3)
- boinc-manager (Boinc Manager 7.9.3)
- boinc-virtualbox (Metapackage 7.9.3)
- boinc-client-nvidia-cuda (Metapackage 7.9.3)
- libboinc7 (Libraries 7.9.3)
- virtualbox (Virtual Box 5.2.44)
- virtualbox-ext-pack (Extension Pack 5.2.44)

Confirmed that virtualization was on by running `lscpu` and found the line that reads:

```
Virtualization:      VT-x
```

**should read VT-x for Intel processors, or AMD-v for AMD processors.*

Also checked that I could start a VM in Virtual Box with virtualization running.

Checked the *client_state.xml* file in the [Boinc Data Directory](https://boinc.berkeley.edu/wiki/BOINC_Data_directory) (found in *var/lib/boinc-client*) to make sure there was a line that reads:

```
<p_vm_extensions_disabled>0</p_vm_extensions_disabled>
```

**should be 0 or absent. If it has a one, you need to make sure you've closed Boinc and ended all its processes, edit it, and save it as an ascii-file.*

Also checked my firewall, local resources, anti-virus, and ports per [this thread](https://lhcathome.cern.ch/lhcathome/forum_thread.php?id=4161&postid=29359#29359).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Boinc's Ubuntu installation instructions](https://boinc.berkeley.edu/wiki/Installing_BOINC_on_Ubuntu) and [LHC's blog post on the subject](https://lhcathome.web.cern.ch/boinc-complains-virtualbox-not-installed-what-do) weren't much help. A VirtualBox upgrade is what finally fixed this error for me. Here's what I did.

First, make sure Boinc and all its processes are closed and then update your packages:

```
sudo service boinc-client stop
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

**1. Install newest Virtualbox:** Then import Oracle's public keys:

```
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox_2016.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -  
wget -q https://www.virtualbox.org/download/oracle_vbox.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

Add the Oracle VirtualBox PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic contrib"
```

Install VirtualBox 6.0 or newer:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install virtualbox-6.0
```

Start the Boinc Manager from your apps panel, and go to *Tools > Event Log...* and look for a line that says something like:

```
Wed 16 Feb 2022 11:38:05 AM CST |  | VirtualBox version: 6.0.24r139119
```

If you see something like that, everything should be working.

**2. Install boinc-virtualbox and start Boinc:** This is a metapackage that adds a series of dependencies from the contrib section to the regular boinc package.

```
sudo apt-get install boinc-virtualbox
sudo service boinc-client start
```

**3. Check virtualization:** You can double check that virtualization is active on your LHC page. Just browse to your publicly listed computer info page, which should be something like:

```
https://lhcathome.cern.ch/lhcathome/show_host_detail.php?hostid=12345678
```

...where 12345678 is your Computer ID, which can be found by going to your Boinc Manager and clicking on LHC@home in your project list and selecting properties. When you go to your LHC computer info page, it should says something like:

```
Virtualization  Virtualbox (6.0.24r139119) installed, CPU has hardware virtualization support and it is enabled
```

The solution was relatively simple, but it sure wasted a lot of time since there weren't any good instructions posted anywhere. If this saves you some time, please  consider giving this solution or problem an up vote. Thank you, and happy crunching!

**UPDATE:** Each time you update your Linux headers, you will have to reinstall boinc-virtualbox:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall boinc-virtualbox
sudo service boinc-client restart
```